# Не могу укротить размеры колонок в DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Визуально форма выглядит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но не могу понять, почему у меня не получается сделать так, чтобы колонки DataGrid занимали облость равномерно, а не находились в углу...

Пробовал экспериментировать с `auto`, но не к чему хорошему не пришел...

Вот моя разметка:

```
<Window x:Class="DictionaryCreator.UI.Windows.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="1380">
    <Grid>
        <b:Interaction.Triggers>
            <b:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
                <b:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding AfterLoadInitCommand}"/>
            </b:EventTrigger>
        </b:Interaction.Triggers>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="387*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" ShowsPreview="False" Width="4"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.RowSpan="2" ></GridSplitter>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
            <Button Command="{Binding Path=ConfigSourceCommand}">Настроить</Button>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2">
            <Button Command="{Binding ConfigDictionaryCommand}">Настроить</Button>
        </Grid>

        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Column="0" >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <StackPanel   Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <GroupBox >
                    <GroupBox.Header>
                        Фильтрация
                    </GroupBox.Header>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <DockPanel Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <Button Height="30" MinWidth="100" Command="{Binding ShowAllCommand}">Все</Button>
                            <Button Height="30" Command="{Binding ShowBindedCommand}">Только привязанные</Button>
                            <Button Height="30" Command="{Binding ShowNotBindedCommand}">Только не привязанные</Button>
                        </DockPanel>
                        <DockPanel Grid.Row="1">
                            <Label>Фильтрация по частичному совпадению</Label>
                            <TextBox Name="seachTextBox" MinWidth="200">
                                <TextBox.InputBindings>
                                    <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding FilterSourceCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Text, ElementName=seachTextBox}"/>
                                </TextBox.InputBindings>
                            </TextBox>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </GroupBox>
                <GroupBox Header="Действия">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <Button>Принудительно привязать</Button>
                        <Button>Принудительно отвязать</Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </GroupBox>
            </StackPanel>
            <Grid Grid.Row="1">

</Grid>
            <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding SourceDataView}" 
                      HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                      VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSourceData}" ColumnWidth="*">

                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Width="auto" Header="Значение" Binding="{Binding Key}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Width="auto" Header="Кол-во" Binding="{Binding Count}" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Column="2">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <GroupBox Header="Действия">
                    <DockPanel>
                        <Button Height="30" 
                                Command="{Binding UnionDictValuesCommand}" 
                                CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=DictDataGrid, Path=SelectedItems}">Объединить</Button>
                        <Button Height="30" 
                                Command="{Binding RemoveDictValuesCommandCommand}" 
                                CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=DictDataGrid, Path=SelectedItems}">Удалить и отвязать</Button>
                    </DockPanel>
                </GroupBox>
            </StackPanel>
            <DataGrid Name="DictDataGrid" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding DictionaryDataView}" ColumnWidth="*">
                <b:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <b:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                        <b:InvokeCommandAction CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItems}" 
                                               Command="{Binding SelectedItemsCommand }" />
                    </b:EventTrigger>
                </b:Interaction.Triggers>
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Button>Настроить алгоритм</Button>
            <Button Command="{Binding LoadDataCommand}">Загрузить</Button>
            <Button Command="{Binding NormalizeAndAddCommand}">Нормализовать и добавить</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Будет замечательно, если кто-нибудь еще подскажет, как сделать так, чтобы размеры левого и правого

Comment: `Пробовал экспериментировать с auto` - `auto`, это "Займи пожалуйста столько места, сколько в тебе требует его контент". А вот `*`, это уже "займи все доступное пространство". `так, чтобы размеры левого и правого` - чего чего?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ ну т.е по полам, чтобы 50% одной колонки и 50% другой

Comment: Ну я вроде уже вам сказал, как это делается) [Ставьте звезды](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POTgO.png).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ В DataGrid.Columns?

Comment: Можно еще задавать в "частях", например вы хотите, чтобы левая колонка занимала 1/3, а вторая 2/3, тогда будет Width будет `*1` и `*2` соответственно.

Comment: @iluxa1810 Скрин ведь выше дал с примером, вы очень невнимательны... Да, у каждой колонки задайте ей `Width` со звездочкой и будет все разделено поровну.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, а я так и сделал, но не работает... Вероятно какой-то контейнер сверху оказывает какое-то влияние.

Comment: Я вот чего заметил. Если заменить в верхнем контейнере на ColumnDefinition Width="*", то форма открывается, как на скриншоте, но если сдвинуть сплиттер в сторону, то оно само масштабируется в нужный размер... Как сделать, чтобы оно без лишних телодвижений норм открывалось?